# what is difference between data center manager and data center administrator

Tags: untagged

can anyone bring out the difference between what is expected from a Data Center Manager and a Data Center Administrator?

Comment: I suspect it depends on who's paying them.  Employers usually get to define roles; sysadmin Q&A sites, not so much.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but it's not a good question for Server Fault -- Like MadHatter said the title applied to a given role varies pretty widely depending on where you work. [Brent's answer](http://serverfault.com/a/465890/32986) covers the general division though - In a place that has both titles one is usually "management" and the other is a grunt that actually does the work.

Comment: To add to @voretaq7 you may have better luck with posting this question on [Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq), but check their FAQ first to make sure it is acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Titles vary by every place you might work...

Regardless, the DC Manager is probably responsible for the entire data center, has multiple supervisors and others below them.  May only be responsible for certain aspects of the DC such as only cabinets and servers, or could actually be responsible for the entire facility, much like a General Manager type of position.  Again this all varies.

The DC administrator is someone who would report to one of the aforementioned supervisors or managers.  This person is often responsible for actually making changes to things, monitoring devices and deploying new stuff.

Again, this all varies across the board but should give you a good separation of responsibilities from a general view point.